# Intersection degree of noncomplete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, hilbert-polynomial

Via the theory of hilbert polynomials, I think the following is true:

Suppose $X$ is a closed subscheme of $P^n$ of degree $d$, and $Y$ is also such one but is also a complete intersection and also doesn't share any component with $X$, then (assuming the the sum of dimensions is at least $n$)

$$deg(X \cap Y) = deg(X) \cdot deg(Y)$$

To prove this, it suffices to show this for $Y$ a hypersurface $f$, which is proved via the exact sequence

$$ S_*(X) \to ^f S_* (X) \to S_*(X)/(f)$$

Is this true if $X,Y$ are not complete intersection?

Comment: Are you assuming that the dimensions of $X,Y$ add up to $n$? Otherwise even for complete intersections it could be wrong.

Comment: @Mohan Woops I'll fix it, I'm assuming like you're saying that the intersection is nonempty (this is the condition if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jake brought an example that illustrates the problems that occur when $Y$ is a complete intersection in a bad way. Let me show that everything goes wrong when both are not complete intersections.

In $P^4$, a union of two generic planes is not a complete intersection (note they meet at a point). Take two pairs (of union of two planes) that all meet the same point. I claim they do the job. Each is certainly of degree $2$, so you'd expect the intersection to be of degree $4$. But, computing the Hilbert polynomial; one easily finds it's $5$ instead!

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. The intersection you describe should result in a point of multiplicity at least 5, perhaps exactly 5. The degree can’t be *lower* than predicted by intersection theory unless the intersection has the wrong dimension.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Oops you're right, it's exactly 5. However, could you explain why you expected it to overestimate 4? My intuition to why I thought in noncomplete intersection it would be lower is express $X$ as a union of two complete intersections (the planes) $X_1, X_2$, then with each we expect intersection of size $2$.  Now intersecting with $X$ is intuitively smaller than adding the intersection with each.

Comment: The intersection contains the point together with its entire (4-dimensional) Zariski tangent space. In particular, the Zariski tangent space at the singular point of a union of two 2-planes is 4-dimensional. (Put another way, the ideal does not contain any linear forms, so the coordinate ring of the intersection has length at least 5.)

Comment: It is not in general true that union commutes with intersection when it comes to scheme structure. (It’s true set-theoretically, at least for varieties.) Instead $(X \cap A) \cup (X \cap B) \subseteq X \cap (A \cup B)$ and similarly $X \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq (X \cup A) \cap (X \cup B)$.

Comment: (I hope I got those right.)

Comment: @JakeLevinson Thanks, wonderuful explanation

Answer (score 2):

It’s false.

In $\mathbb{P}^4$ with coordinates $x,y,z,w,t$, let $X$ be the union of the planes $x=y=0$ and $z=w=0$ and let $Y$ be the plane $x-z=y-w=0$, a complete intersection.

Then you can check that $X \cap Y$ is a point of multiplicity $3$, but $\deg(X)\deg(Y)=2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: I should have been more careful; indeed the problem here is that $Y$ is a complete intersection only in a way so that the hypersurfaces contain $X$, so the proof really fails (i.e even though $Y$ doesn't share a component with $X$ the way it's a complete intersection did). I was hoping for an example when they're both not complete intersection